# How to get the delta of a metric in a time interval

Tags: monitoring, graphite, grafana

I'm trying to get the delta of a metric in the edges of a time interval in Graphite, but I couldn't find anything related to it in the documentation.

I'm not looking for the derivation, but the absolute difference.

Is using `summarize(nonNegativeDerivative(a.metric), "30mins")` will do the job ?

I be glad if someone can point me to the right function, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The graphite `nonNegativeDerivative` function isn't a "true" derivative, it will return the delta between successive points, which seems to be what you're looking for.

The "true" derivative function in graphite is `perSecond` which returns the delta normalized to a per-second rate.

So, try using `nonNegativeDerivative` without the `summarize` wrapper and see if that gives you what you're looking for.